# Strip a string until occurance of a character or characters

Tags: string, tcl

I am not much skilled in TCL hence requesting help to provide required mechanism to achieve the below output:

Suppose I have a string who value is *"He served food(readymade icecream);"*

I want the substring out of this main string as "*readymade icecream);*"

Further is it possible to further strip of the main string to get substring as "*readymade icecream*"

Here are my attempts but it is not working:

```
string trim $str "("
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To trim from the left:

```
 set ix [string first ( $s]
 if {$ix >= 0} {
     incr ix
     set s [string range $s $ix end]
 }
 # else the string does not contain '('
```

To trim from the right:

```
 set ix [string last ) $s]
 if {$ix >= 0} {
     incr ix -1
     set s [string range $s 0 $ix]
 }
 # else the string does not contain ')'
```

See the [manual](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/string.htm) [pages](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/incr.htm) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

This is a case where regular expressions are the right thing to use:

```
if {[regexp {\(([^()]*)\)} $str -> substring]} {
    puts "found $substring in parentheses"
} else {
    puts "did not find anything suitable"
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But is it possible to get the values independently - I mean trim until a character from right or left of the string